# How to relay a SSL HttpRequest through a server with TCPListener?

Tags: c#, ssl, proxy, tcplistener

Sorry for the poor title, but basically what I am trying to achieve is have an application that will use a TCPListener to wait for incoming connections and then forward those to their intended destination.  Forwarding regular Http requests is easy enough, but what steps do I need to take in order to "proxy" an HTTPS connection?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't read the content of HTTPS communications without being either the source or the destination. Nobody in the middle can eavesdrop. So, unless you know the destination before-hand (say, if someone manages to send you the target IP out-of-band), you're stuck.

NITPICK EDIT: That's not entirely true. You could pretend to be the destination and interfere with the handshaking process. You *will*  be able to see the content of the request, but the user will see an incorrect-certificate warning.

Comment: You can't get the server-side certificates in any reasonable real-world scenario...

Comment: Yes (I tried to write it in my answer too...), also FoxyGT did not specify if he need a generic solution or want to do it for his private server - giving poster benefit of a doubt and not assuming pure evil intentions of creating generic middle-man proxy.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have some control on client, I don't see a way to "proxy" a https connection.

- If it is possible to change the proxy settings of the client you can pretend to be a SOCKS proxy.
- If if is possible to add a new entry to client's hosts file(as if you are the destination), you can bypass the communication.

But no way to read the content of the session.

Answer (score 0):

It is actually quite easy in theory - you just need to know complete server certificate and potentially client certificate if one is used, than correctly implement handshake for both sides.

In practice - you have no way to obtain SSL certificate for server unless you own it, and the same for client certificate.

I'd recommend reading explanation how Fiddler does HTTPS decryption: http://www.fiddler2.com/Fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp